# Use data attribute in function

Tags: javascript

I have the following HTML:

```
<select class="select optional" data-minimumresultsforsearch="10" 
  data-query="function (query) {var data = {results: []}, i, j, s; for (i = 1; i &lt; 5; i++) {s = &quot;&quot;; for (j = 0; j &lt; i; j++) {s = s + query.term;} data.results.push({id: query.term + i, text: s});} query.callback(data);}" 
  id="user_default_locale" name="user[default_locale]"></select>
```

I need to find a javascript function that loops over all the elements like select.  That's the part that I found myself :-)

```
document.getElementsByTagName('select')
```

But now I need to call them all like this:

```
$("user_default_locale").select2({
            minimumresultsforsearch: 10,
            query: function (query) {
                var data = {results: []}, i, j, s;
                for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                    s = "";
                    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {s = s + query.term;}
                    data.results.push({id: query.term + i, text: s});
                }
                query.callback(data);
            }
        });
```

Anyone know how to do this?

EDIT:

Ok I now have this:

```
  $('select').each(function(idx, elem) {
  var $elem = $(elem);
  var VarMinimumResultsForSearch = $elem.data('minimumResultsForSearch');
  var VarPlaceholder = $elem.data('placeholder');

  $elem.select2({minimumResultsForSearch: VarMinimumResultsForSearch || undefined, placeholder: VarPlaceholder || undefined});
  });
```

And with this it does execute the select2 however not with the params...

```
<select class="select optional" data-minimumresultsforsearch="1" data-placeholder="JOS" 
  id="user_default_locale" name="user[default_locale]">
```

Comment: Having a func in data sounds like a terribly wrong design decision.

Comment: Why not create an object that maps id attributes of select lists to functions, and use that to lookup the functions?

Comment: The HTML is build from in rails. Ok function in the data is maybe overboard but my question still stand with multiple data attributes: data-minimumresultsforsearch  data-allowclear  data-minimuminputlength  ...

Comment: Since you seem to be using jQuery, why use `getElementsByTagName`?

Comment: Hi Jan, no idea, as I said, total newbie as far as javascript goes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to loop over selects, here is what you might want to try:

```
var funcs = {
    'func1': function() { .... },
    'func2': function() { .... }
}


$('select').each(function(idx, elem) {
    var $elem = $(elem);
    var foo = $elem.data('foo');
    var bar = $elem.data('bar');
    var funcKey = $elem.data('func-key');
    var callback = funcs[funcKey];

    $elem.select2(blah blah);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  How does this take the data attributes and put them in the function?  Sorry I'm a real javascript newbie.  The function I want to call is fix, that's always select2()  However the data elements can be none to ...

Comment: You can provide a default value for your data like this: `select2({someParam: foo ? foo : 'default'});` The `x ? y : z` is called a conditional expression, and the `? :` is called conditional operator. Check out this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: You can also use the or operator: `select2({someParam: foo || 'default'});` where `||` is the or operator. More on that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: So it is not possible to do it dynamically?  You need to specify all the possible params in advance.  Only the values can be dynamically?  Is that correct?

Comment: You don't need to omit params. Unless select2 is broken in some major way, passing `undefined` as default should be the same as not passing the parameter at all.

Comment: Ok I changed question based on your feedback. Not completely working however.

Comment: `minimumResultsForSearch` is not the same as `minimumresultsforsearch`. I suggest you stick to camel-case since that's more readable, but using dashes is more common (e.g., `minimum-results-for-search`. (Personally, I'd just shorten it to `min-results`). :)

Comment: I make sure it's named correctly but it made no difference.  I now used console and noticed that if I put any capital char in the data attributes it didn't work.  Probably has to do with rails.  Removed it and now it works.  Thanks!